# How to set `tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers`?

Tags: init-file, tabbar

According to the docs of  `tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers` :

> List of modifier keys for selecting tab-bar tabs by their numbers.
>
> Possible modifier keys are control, meta, shift, hyper, super and alt.
> Pressing one of the modifiers in the list and a digit selects the tab
> whose number equals the digit (see tab-bar-select-tab).
> The digit 9 selects the last (rightmost) tab (see tab-last).
> The digit 0 selects the most recently visited tab (see tab-recent).
>
> For easier selection of tabs by their numbers, consider customizing tab-bar-tab-hints, which will show tab numbers alongside the tab name.

so I set it something like this in my configuration file :

```lisp
(setq tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers "super")
```

but it doesn't do anything ( pressing `s-1` says it's not bound to anything ), am I setting it correctly or is there something I am missing here ?

---

**Emacs version:** GNU Emacs 29.0.50

**OS :** MacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`M-x customize-variable RET tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers`***

[image: M-x customize-variable RET tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers]

Put a click mark and click `Apply and Save`.  That gives me

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(tab-bar-select-tab-modifiers '(super)))
```